# CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. (no solution yet)

Tags: gradle

### 2 days ago it worked ok, now it does this, thank you for your answers

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.21f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradleOut'.

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
> platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
> To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
> Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
]
stdout[

> Configure project :
> WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
> The current default is 'true'.

Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-28\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-28\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-28\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
File C:\Users\Ziga.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 29 in C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 29 not accepted.
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0) UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:281)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)

Answer (score 0):

While building make sure you are connected to good internet connection. It might be that you have you have changed to the target api version which is not yet installed. Unity can download that version while building apk if connected to internet (It installed for me). If any sdk installation window opens while building apk and prompts for accepting any license agreement, just accept it. Also make sure that your firewall is not blocking unity (openjdk and unityhub might need access too).

Answer (score 0):

in my case

i was connected mobile data 4G and i build unity project i have same error Gradle failed than i connected Wi-Fi than  no error found and build was success full. You have good internet connection to build unity project

Answer (score 0):

if is bundle version 0 change to 1

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue went away when I fixed another error caused by duplicate library classes. I went to Assets/Plugins/Android, clicked on the culprit (in my case it was the "com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.5.0" plugin and then unchecked Android as a selected platform for the plugin.
After this, I was able to build.

[image: Screenshot]